# How to fix AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'function'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I'm totally new to Python and I currently working on the program in Michael Nielsen's online book: "neural-networks-and-deep-learning", while I'm trying to run a pre-made module named mnist_loader.py, a function named load_data_wrapper() within the module is not attributed.

The link of the code can be found here: https://github.com/mnielsen/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/blob/master/src/mnist_loader.py

Here's the code for the module, mnist_loader.py:

```
import cPickle

import gzip

import numpy as np

def load_data():
    f = gzip.open('../data/mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
    training_data, validation_data, test_data = cPickle.load(f)
    f.close()
    return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)

def load_data_wrapper():
    tr_d, va_d, te_d = load_data()
    training_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in tr_d[0]]
    training_results = [vectorized_result(y) for y in tr_d[1]]
    training_data = zip(training_inputs, training_results)
    validation_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in va_d[0]]
    validation_data = zip(validation_inputs, va_d[1])
    test_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in te_d[0]]
    test_data = zip(test_inputs, te_d[1])
    return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)

def vectorized_result(j):
    e = np.zeros((10, 1))
    e[j] = 1.0
    return e
```

While I'm trying the run the following code:

```
>>> import mnist_loader
>>> training_data, validation_data, test_data = \
... mnist_loader.load_data_wrapper()
```

The interpreter shows:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'load_data_wrapper'
```

I check the directory and the mnist_loader.py module has no error itself.
Then I tried to take the function load_data_wrapper out and use it by itself by using:

```
from mnist_loader import load_data_wrapper
```

and it shows:

```
ImportError: cannot import name load_data_wrapper
```

I expect the code to load the mnist.pkl.gz file and output MNIST data.

Comment: Do you have another file called "mnist_loader.py" somewhere?

Comment: no this is the only one

Comment: Just want to note that I'm using JupyterLab for the program in case there is anything wrong with the interpreter.

Comment: checked, there is no stale mnist_loader.py

Comment: Add something "loud" to `mnist_loader.py`, like a `print "mint_loader loaded". If you don't see that when you use `import mnist_loader`, you're importing something other than what you think you are.

Comment: It seems like somewhere in your code you may have a function that is called like module.function, have you checked if its being called as an object instead?

Comment: @YuboShao then its not being imported. Copy the file to the same directory and try again. Check you have no typos as its case sensitive.

Comment: I added a print into the module but nothing printed out when I imported it

Comment: it still doesn't work

Comment: I'm currently using Jupyterlab which is a web-based interpreter, should I try it on another local platform like spyder?

Comment: what does `print(mnist_loader)` show? And `print(dir(mnist_loader))`?

Comment: I tried to work on VScode instead of JupyterLab, it works now!! Thank all of you for your helping :DDDDDDD

Answer (score 0):

You need to store it in the same directory, where stored your file, in which you try import.

Oh, if you are using JupyterLab, perhaps, you need to do something like this:

```
$ # Imports the workspace file `file_name.json`.
$ jupyter lab workspaces import file_name.json
Saved workspace: <workspaces-directory>/labworkspacesfoo-54d5.jupyterlab-workspace
```

Items 7.2 & 7.6 here: [JupyterLab manual](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/jupyterlab/latest/jupyterlab.pdf)

Comment: Second this regarding the ImportError.